# Android mp3 cross class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an mp3 sound using the MediaPlayer class inside a regular class, which means non Activity. My problem is probably initializing the MediaPlayer object since i have no Context in a non Activity class. How is this solvable?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is some code from where the function should be called:

```
public class Bullet extends Thread{
public int bx = SniperActivity.bulletx;
public int by = SniperActivity.bullety;
Player obj = new Player();
SniperActivity con = new SniperActivity();


   public void shoot(){

    if (bx == Place.spotx && by == Place.spoty)
    {
            for (int f = 0; f<Rifle.dam; f++)
    {
                Player.life--;
                if(Player.life<=0){
                obj.death();
    }
    try {
        Bullet.sleep(Rifle.rate);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
           }
    }
    int s = 0;
    s++;
    while (s == Rifle.magazine)
    {
        try {
            Bullet.sleep(Rifle.relode);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = 0;
    }
    con.Mplayer.start();
   }
   }
```

The function is called right up here, in the "con.Mplayer.start()" line, from the shoot() function. the con Object is reffering to an Activity that has the Mplayer initialized in it is trying to start it from here.

Here is the activity code:

```
public class SniperActivity extends Activity{


    private GameView game;
    private Player player;
    private Scop scope;
    public static int scopx;
    public static int scopy;
    public static int bulletx;
    public static int bullety;
    public static String filename = "SharedData";
    static SharedPreferences someData;
    public static int Width;
    public static int Height;
    public MediaPlayer Mplayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(SniperActivity.this, R.raw.shot);

    someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0); 
    Height = someData.getInt("height", 480);
    Width = someData.getInt("width", 480);

    scopx = 1;
    scopy = 1;

    PlayerView playerview;
    playerview = new PlayerView(this, player);
    ScopView Scope;
    Scope = new ScopView(this, scope);

    this.game = new GameView(this);
    game.setviews(playerview, Scope);
    setContentView(game);
    int screenWidth,screenHeight;
    screenWidth = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    bulletx = screenWidth/2;
    bullety = screenHeight/2;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float dx;
    Bullet bullet = new Bullet();
    //get the x coordinate of users' press
    dx = event.getX();
     if (dx >=0)
     {
         bullet.shoot();
     }
    return true;
}

public void onDeath(){
    finish();
}


}
```

Comment: The main Android entrypoits Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver have a Context. If one of these create/start the player you can pass the context as @mac suggested. Or do you have something special?

Comment: @k3b i have something special, my mediaplayer is not called by any of these, so i have no context. any solution for this?

Comment: please put some code from where you are calling java class...

Comment: I have added my source code, take a look at it please :)

Comment: @arielschon12: Don't ever do this...`SniperActivity con = new SniperActivity();`. You cannot instantiate an `Activity` using `new`. You should also never attempt to access static methods or fields of an `Activity` such as `SniperActivity.bulletx` from outside of that `Activity`.

Comment: @mac I have added source code, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `Context` in constructor of simple java file

```
PlayMp3 mp3 = new PlayMp3(getApplicatonContext());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though im not quit sure how to do this.. can i have an example please?

Comment: I cant do it, see what i have commented on my question.